# f.select with enum in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, enums

I have model,

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  as_enum :test, [:test, :test_1, :test_1_2]
end
```

I need to create a `f.select` dropdown with `enum`. But I am facing an issue preparing dropdown with `enum`.

Here is my code:

```
<%= f.select :test, options_for_select(Test.tests.keys.to_a), {}, :class => "form-control" %>
```

But prepared a wrong select box.
[image]

http://grab.by/HSM2

Can anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below. Titleize function capitalizes all the words and replaces the underscores with spaces. You can read more about it [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize)

```
<%= f.select :test, Test.tests.keys.map {|test| [test.to_s.titleize, test]}, {}, :class => "form-control" %>
```